# linear programming / vectors / opl / cplex

Tags: vector, linear-programming, cplex, opl

I hope someone can help me. I implemented the following maximization problem in cplex studio:

```
//Parameter

`int n=...;` //number of items

`int c=...;` //number of bundles 

`int k=...;` //number of price vectors

`int m =...;` //number of bidders

range range_M =1..m;

    range range_N =1..n;

    range range_B =1..c;

    range range_K =1..k;

    float vj [range_B][range_M]=...; //Wert von Bündel b 

    float s [range_B]=...; 

//Adjazenzmatrix

int a[range_B][range_N]=...;

//Variablen

dvar boolean x[range_B];

dvar float+ pbk[range_B][range_K];

dvar float+ pb[range_B];

dvar float+ pik[range_N][range_K];

dvar float+ pi[range_N];

dvar float v[range_B];

//Zielfunktion



 maximize sum (b in range_B) (v[b]*x[b]);

//Restriktionen



  subject to {

//Values OR



 forall (b in range_B) v[b]==max(j in range_M) vj[b][j];

//Jedes Item kann nur einmal zugeordnet werden



 forall (i in range_N) sum (b in range_B) a[b][i]*x[b]<=1;

//Preise sind nicht negativ



 forall (i in range_N) pi[i]>=0;

    forall (b in range_B) pb[b]>=0;

    forall (i in range_N) pik[i][k]>=0;

    forall (b in range_B) pbk[b][k]>=0;

        //supporting Preise pbk

        forall (b in range_B, k in range_K) pbk[b][k]<= v[b] +10000*(1-x[b]);

        forall (b in range_B, k in range_K) pbk[b][k]>= v[b]-10000*x[b];    



    //unsold items



forall (i in range_N) pi[i]<=10000*sum(b in range_B)x[b]*a[b][i];

//Lineare Preisvektoren



forall (b in range_B, k in range_K) sum (i in range_N) pik[i][k]*a[b][i]==pbk[b][k];

//Bündel mit nur einem Item



  forall (b in range_B: s[b]==1, i in range_N: a[b][i]==1) pi[i]==pb[b];

//pb Auswahl 

f

orall (b in range_B) pb[b]<= max (k in range_K) pbk [b][k] + 10000*(1-x[b]);

    forall (b in range_B) pb[b]>= min (k in range_K) pbk [b][k] - 10000*x[b];

    forall (b in range_B) pb[b]<= min (k in range_K) pbk [b][k] + 10000*x[b];

    forall (b in range_B) pb[b]>= max (k in range_K) pbk [b][k] - 10000*(1-x[b]);

}
```

Now I want to get more than one vector pb. Lets say k vectors with b elements each. I have introduced another variable pbk[b][k] with k giving the number of vectors. Unfortunately, cplex returns k times the same vector. I have also implemented the same model in Gurobi, which returns k different vectors.

Does anyone have an idea how to get different vectors in cplex as well?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can you post your complete OPL model ?

Comment: Sure! Thank you so much for replying!

Comment: I formatted your code for you @Rubia. To format your code as code, select all the text that is code and then press CTRL + K, it will be auto idented by 4 spaces triggering the code formatting.

Comment: Hi, maybe you get the same vectors since all constraints for all k are the same. Can you try to add a new constraint such as pbk[1][1]>=pbk[1][2]+0.1;

Comment: But why is it that Gurobi returns three different vectors without additional constraints?

Comment: My best guess for the discrepancy would be that you are doing the exact same things in CPLEX and Gurobi. I assume that for Gurobi you somehow translated your .mod to some other format? I suggest to export the CPLEX and Gurobi model as LP file and then compare both to make sure they are indeed the same.